# disable defaault wordpress comments from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, comments, facebook, disqus

I am modifying the facebook comments plugin to my purposes. What I'd like to do is have it remove Wordpress native comments automatically if it is enabled- in fact what I'd really like it to do is use the Wordpress comments settings in the item itself and/or general settings to decide whether it should show or not.

Disqus works like this and its just how you would expect a comments replacement system to work by default- I think this plugin should work like that unless you tell it to do otherwise.

Does anyone have any ideas how disqus achieves this?

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most themes used [`comments_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) to include their comment areas.  It's completely full of filters, one of which is the include file (usually comments.php) that you can hijack to include a file from your plugin that contains all the stuff for facebook comments (or nothing if you just want to disable comments.

Example:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'comments_template', 'wpse35363_comments_template' );
function wpse35363_comments_template( $file )
{
    return plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'path/to/your/file.php';
}
```

As far as general settings and per post settings, those are stored in `wp_options` and `wp_postmeta` respectively.  Take a look at how the default [comments compat file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/theme-compat/comments.php) looks and you should get an idea about how you can do this in your plugin.

Comment: Actually thats not quite what I am after, as it is reliant on the template, I want it to be completely controlled by the plugin- like disqus. With the disqus plugin, it doesn't matter what template you are using, if disqus is enabled then wordpress native comments dont show up. This is what I want to know how to do...

Comment: I promise you that this is the way to do it.  In fact, it's the way Disqus does it.  http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/disqus-comment-system/trunk/disqus.php

Comment: Ok got that sussed now, thanks very much! A couple of interesting observations. All I ended up doing was taking the content of the function fbcommentbox and added it into a seperate 'comments.php' file and changed the original function so it just had the line return dirname(__FILE__) . '/comments.php'; in it and added the line add_filter( 'comments_template', 'fbcommentbox'); after that. Intresting to note is that comments.php seems to get the variables- which I didn't expect, and also that you need to go via comments.php or it doesn't work...